# Intellij IDEA Apache Tomcat. How to edit images?

Tags: java, image, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm learning web programming on Java and encountered a problem. 
I use Intellij Idea with a plugin

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
</plugin>
```

to run local server and test my code. 
The thing is I don't know how to edit my images. I use

```
<div align="center"><img src="Images/logo.jpg"/></div>
```

and it works fine, but when I decided to change the size of my logo and recopied it to my Images folder Tomcat doesn't see the changes when he stars up. I get the same size jpg as I first copied it there.
I think I know what's the problem. My guess is that Tomcat copied it somewhere only once at the first run and doesn't care about any changes in a file with the same name at each next run. He just using the "old" version. But the thing is I don't know how to make him recopy (or something) this file, or any file. Also I couldn't find the path where he stores it to delete it manually and force him to get the "new" version in such a way. Maybe someone can give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will read the images from the war file which gets packaged for your application, so changing the file in the project in the ide wouldn't change the war. Depending on how you are running it I would guess that you need to rebuild the war file after making your changes. Try a fresh 'mvn clean install' before running tomcat. If that doesn't work you may need to provide more information about your workspace and project set up and how it is being run.